# AMF parser issue

Tags: rest, mulesoft, raml, advanced-rest-client, anypoint-platform

When using Advanced Rest Client I am getting an error when I try to download one of my projects from Anypoint Exchange. It is a REST asset written in RAML. The mocking service works correctly and the Design Center project displays no errors. The error states

> "AMF parser: Unable to resolve AMF Id+model. Cannot read property 'TK' of null".

Is there some kind of formatting required for this to work?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what are you doing. What is the request exactly (URL, method, headers, body)? Have you tried with some other method or client? HTTP status of the response?

Comment: AMF is an external library. I saw similar errors with some API specs in the past and I reported it to the AMF team. However I can't do much about it. If you could send and API I can use to reproduce I would take a look myself.